# 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, telnet, cmd.exe

I'm working on an InfoSec exercise, specifically sending emails in cmd that makes use of telnet. Unfortunately, I can't start it. I'm receiving the "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." from cmd when I type telnet. Can someone please tell me on what to install and its procedures for me to access telnet command in CMD. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have also posted a question asking about port issues with `telnet` can we assume you have solved this problem? http://superuser.com/questions/734605/connection-on-port-25-fails

Answer (score 54):

I hope you are using Windows 7.

Telnet is disabled by default, so to enable it follow these steps:

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Go to Programs & Features
3. In left bar select "Turn Windows features on or off"
4. Find "Telnet Client" and tick it
5. Click "OK"

Telnet should be working now.

Comment: It worked. Btw can you please help me with this: http://superuser.com/questions/734966/550-user-unknown-cmd-telnet-error-email-spoofing

Comment: Great thank you!  Also `netstat -a` is great way to discover open and connected ports.  [YouTube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miCZO_1YUZQ)

Comment: Works for Windows 10 too. Thanks.

Comment: Windows 11 Pro too.

Answer (score 13):

Telnet is a Windows feature that needs to be enabled.

Control Panel > Programs & Features > Turn Windows features on or off > check the box at Telnet Client

Comment: Got it. Can you please help me with this: http://superuser.com/questions/734966/550-user-unknown-cmd-telnet-error-email-spoofing

Answer (score 4):

You can [install telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) by using [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824821.aspx) command-line tool, e.g.:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

or using `pkgmgr` (deprecated in favor of above):

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

#### Usage

The syntax is:

```
telnet example.com 80
```

where `example.com` is your destination host (can be `localhost` for local PC) and `80` is the port number.

When you connect, to disconnect, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, then type `quit` command to exit.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I'm on an Amazon Workspace Windows 10 machine, and the other answers that talk about control panel didn't apply. When I clicked "Turn Windows features on or off", it took me to something called "Server Manager". If there's a telnet checkbox in there, it must be many layers deep. This command-line based solution worked great! Just be sure you start Command Prompt as an administrator.